# Missing one item when calculating sum of each element and its neighbors

Tags: python, list

I have a list `list1` whose elements are random between 1 and 100, and its length is a random number between 3 and 21.

```
import random

list1 = []
start = 1
end = random.randint(3, 21)
for i in range(start, end + 1):
    list1.append(random.randrange(1, 101, 1))

print("My list length is", end)
print("List1 (Original List):", list1)
```

My aim is to create a new list with the same number of elements as `list1`, such that each element is the sum of the same element in `list1` and its left and right neighbors. (Since the first element does not have a left-hand neighbor and the rightmost element does not have a right-hand neighbor I will not include them.)

I have tried to write this code but the output is not the same element number as `list1`.

```
list2 = (
    [list1[0] + list1[1]]
    + [list1[i-1] + list1[i] + list1[i+1] for i in range(1, len(list1)-2)]
    + [list1[-2] + list1[-1]]
)
print(list2)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Should `range(1, len(list1)-2)` be `range(1, len(list1)-1)`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `for i range(x,y)` iterates from `x` (inclusive) to `y` (exclusive). In your case, the biggest `i = len(list1)-3`. This means you don't reach all the elements. You could fix it by changing it to `for i in range(1, len(list1)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

### A Scientific Approach

I believe python has a lot of ground to cover, it is not only to learn it from an algorithmic point of view, but learning the pythonic approach is more valuable, and then maybe more scientific ways to do computations.

That's why along with all the answers, I present another solution by using the convolution operation, which is a more general mathematical operation of what you are doing only an instance of it, more precisely, you want to convolve a given array with the following filter: `[1, 1, 1]`.

This can be done using `numpy` library, by its `convolve` function, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

np.convolve([1,2,3,4], [1,1,1])
>>> array([1, 3, 6, 9, 7, 4])

np.convolve([1,2,3,4], [1,1,1], 'same')
>>> array([3, 6, 9, 7])

np.convolve([1,2,3,4], [1,1,1], 'valid')
>>> array([6, 9])
```

I encourage you to read through the doc and learn more about it. I just wanted to show that learning python can be a very big step, plan for it.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

**Your code:**

```
list2=[]
list2=[list1[0]+list1[1]] + [list1[i-1]+list1[i]+list1[i+1] for i in range(1,len(list1)-2)]+ [list1[-2]+list1[-1]]
print (list2)
```

**My code**

```
list2=[]
list2=[list1[0]+list1[1]] + [list1[i-1]+list1[i]+list1[i+1] for i in range(1,len(list1)-1)]+ [list1[-2]+list1[-1]]
print (list2)
```

In your code you already included 1st element and you started loop from 1 i.e. you already neglected it. You don't need to neglect again in for loop stop condition so change 2 to 1 that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extend` and `append` to a list as follows:

```
list2 = [list1[0]+list1[1]]
list2.extend([(list1[i-1]+list1[i]+list1[i+1]) for i in range(1, len(list1)-1)])
list2.append(list1[-1]+list1[-2])

print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this. using a function to generate required list.

```
import random
list1=[]
start= 1
end= random.randint(3, 21)
for i in range(start, end + 1):
    list1.append(random.randrange(1,101,1))
print ("My list length is",end)
print ("List1 (Original List):",list1)

def neighborsList(alist):
    new_list = []
    length_of_list = len(alist)
    for i in range(length_of_list):
        if i == 0:
            new_list.append(alist[i]+ alist[i+1])
        elif i == (length_of_list-1):
            new_list.append(alist[i-1] + alist[i])
        else:
            new_list.append(alist[i-1] + alist[i]+ alist[i+1])
    
    return new_list


print('Newly created List: ',neighborsList(list1))
```

Comment: why did this is been marked as  not useful, this is working, any efficiency issue?

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! @udimax

Answer (score -1):

What about this approach?

```
list1.insert(0,0)
list1.append(0)
list2=[i+j+k for i,j,k in zip(list1[2:],list1[:-2],list1[1:-1])]
```

List1

```
[98, 58, 44, 69, 20, 65, 96, 75, 86, 37, 76, 27, 66, 37]
```

List2

```
[156, 200, 171, 133, 154, 181, 236, 257, 198, 199, 140, 169, 130, 103]
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a much cleaner solution

```
import random

list1 = []
list2 = []

# Create random list
for i in range(1, random.randint(3, 21) + 1):
    list1.append(random.randrange(1,101,1))

# Get length of list
len_list1 = len(list1)

# for every index and element in random list
for index, element in enumerate(list1):
    
    # if first element
    if index == 0:
        
        # only append next item
        list2.append(list1[index]+list1[index+1])

    # if last element
    elif index == (len_list1-1):
        
        # only append last item
        list2.append(list1[index]+list1[index-1])
    
    else:
        
        # append sum to new list
        list2.append(list1[index-1]+element+list1[index+1])


print(list1)
print(list2)
```

something like this

```
list2 = (
    [list1[0] + list1[1]]
    + [list1[i-1] + list1[i] + list1[i+1] for i in range(1, len(list1)-2)]
    + [list1[-2] + list1[-1]]
)
print(list2)
```

is unreadable code.